# Want both PHP & JS form (empty fields/password match) validation?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, validation

I am designing an e-shop that allows profile registration. I need to have both Javascript & PHP validation for the registration form. (so when any of the fields are empty, I need to get a pop-up message that lets me know which specific field is empty + display on the screen beside the required field a visual message to advise the user where they need to correct the issue)

so far it is not working because my JS validation form activates onsubmit and my PHP is on action. I realize onsubmit activates before action and thus not allowing 'action' to go through.

I tried changing it from 'action' to 'onclick', but onsubmit also activates first and does not allow the PHP to work.

Here's my code for the form (I only included the first name portion so it won't get too long)

```
<form method="post" onclick="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" style="border:1px solid #ccc">

  <label><b>First Name</b></label>
<input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="">
  <?php echo $fnameErr;?>

<button type="submit" class="signupbtn" name="submit">Submit</button>
```

Here's my PHP code:

```
 <?php

    $fnameErr = "";
    $fname = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
       if (empty($_POST["firstName"])) {
            $fnameErr = "Name is required";
             } 
         else {
            $fname = test_input($_POST["firstName"]);
              }
             }

      function test_input($data) {
          $data = trim($data);
          $data = stripslashes($data);
          $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
          return $data;
        }
  ?>
```

I know the PHP code works, because if I delete the JS validation, it works as intended. I appreciate the help.

Please let me know if I need to add any extra information. Also, this hasn't been my first stop. I've been googling and trying to figure out how to fix this issue for hours to no avail...

This is the JS function being called (which also works as intended) this is also the shortened version to include only the name, the rest works the same, more if statements:

```
   function validateForm() {
   "use strict";
var fn = document.forms.myForm.firstName.value;
var ln = document.forms.myForm.lastName.value;
var em = document.forms.myForm.email.value;
var phone = document.forms.myForm.phone.value;
var pass = document.forms.myForm.psw.value;
var pass2 = document.forms.myForm.psw2.value;
if (fn === "") {
    window.alert("First name must be filled out");
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: If you know the PHP code works, wouldn't it be wise to show us the javascript instead?

Comment: Please post your javascript code

Comment: @Salketer I added the JS code, however it works as well. It's the combination of the two that stops the PHP from working.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" name="firstName" required>
```

You don't need any JavaScript.

Furthermore:

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

You don't need to specify the `action` if you're posting back to the current page. Using `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` is potentially a vulnerability if you're not careful, and also breaks "pretty URLs" if you have them.

Comment: I know I don't need JS, I realize it would be much easier to simply add the required tag there... But I am trying to learn how to make both JS & PHP validation work. As for the action, if I keep it blank, would the PHP still work?

Answer (score 0):

You should change your `onsubmit` part and remove the `onclick`. Also your form is not valid as there is no `action`.

```js
    
    document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit',validateForm);
    function validateForm(e) {
        "use strict";
        console.log(document.forms.myForm.firstName.value);
        var fn = document.forms.myForm.firstName.value;
        
        if (fn === "") {
            window.alert("First name must be filled out");
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

```html
<form action="https://stackoverflow.com/" method="post" id="myForm">
  <input type="text" name="firstName" >
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

There was a couple mistakes... But mainly what cause your problem is that onsubmit="return validateForm()". I also added e.preventDefault() it is to prevent the form submission if there is an error.

Comment: HTML5 makes `action` optional and default to the current page (and browsers have always been doing this anyway)

Comment: I tried that and my PHP works, but my JS doesn't work anymore ( I don't get the window alert)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Thanks, wasn't aware it got remove in html5... Guess I'm too old! lol

Comment: `onsubmit="return validateForm(event);"` would be correct.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I tried that and the JS did not work as well, I also tried "return validateForm(e)" and "return validateForm(event)"

Comment: I'm sorry guys, been a while since I used inline event handlers... There, I made a fully functional (and tested) solution.

Comment: @Salketer I appreciate it. However, your solution only handles the JS part of the code. The problem is making both JS & PHP work..

Comment: @Salketer btw when I tried your code with my code, the window.alert doesn't work for some reason, only the PHP part works...

Comment: Well, in my code both work, so you certainly are doing something different...  And by the way, I'd really really suggest you get things straight in one language before getting to another. If you do not have good understanding of any of the languages, it's gonna be very hard to make them work together.

Answer (score 0):

As said by @Niet The Dark Absol you can use the `required` but if you insist you can add `e.preventdefault` to prevent form from submitting in case of errors. We can elaborate properly if we can have a glimpse at your Javascript function.

Comment: `function validateForm() {
   "use strict";
var fn = document.forms.myForm.firstName.value;
...
if (fn === "") {
      e.preventDefault
    window.alert("First name must be filled out");
    return false;
  }else
  // use .submit() method to submit the form
} ` you should handle this function on a button onClick

Comment: I tried that as it was displayed above, the JS is not working completely unfortunately..

Comment: I suggest you give your Form elements id each and use the getElementById('id').value and trigger the function when the pages finishes loading if the script works use an onClick() handler on your Submit button

Comment: whenever I would add an Onclick to load my JS function, my JS function works but my PHP doesn't have a chance to work

Comment: In that case you can be able to access php through script using Ajax and wait for a response from your php file

Comment: that's beyond my understanding unfortunately.. I'm at the basic level of PHP and JS, still learning...